# Meson build system + C/C++ LibraryLink, help needed for portability check/fix (Windows &MacOs)

Tags: packages, librarylink, testing-and-verification, c++

As a proof of concept I have created a [github repository](https://github.com/vincent-picaud/mma_meson_demo) that shows how to:

> use the [Meson build system](https://mesonbuild.com/) to create a Mathematica package using [LibraryLink functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/tutorial/InteractionWithMathematica.html)

The goal is to provide an **easy to use** and
**portable** solution for C/C++ projects using LibraryLink.

I have tested it under Linux for MMA version 10.0 and 11.2.

The idea is quite simple: we can have a look on how the `CreateLibrary[]` function works:

```
CreateLibrary["", "foo", 
              "ShellCommandFunction" -> Print, 
              "TargetDirectory" -> $TemporaryDirectory]
```

On my computer I get:

> /usr/bin/gcc -shared -o
>   "/tmp/Working-is231575-25315-2262167744-3/foo.so" -m64 -fPIC -O2 
>   -I"/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.2/SystemFiles/IncludeFiles/C" -I"/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.2/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions"
>   "/tmp/Working-is231575-25315-2262167744-3/foo.c" 
>   -L"/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.2/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions"
>   -L"/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.2/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64"
>   2>&1

Nothing too surprising here: `-shared -m64 -fPIC -O2` are the regular flags to create a dynamic lib, there are two include directories (`-I` flag) and two directories to search for mma dynamic libs (the `-L` flags that are forwarded to the linker)

To get the information for automatic build using Meson I process as follows:

```
libraryLinkIncludeDirectories = {FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory,
     "SystemFiles", "IncludeFiles", "C"}], 
  FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Links", 
    "MathLink", "DeveloperKit", $SystemID, "CompilerAdditions"}]}
libraryInstallDirectory = {FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, 
    "SystemFiles", "LibraryResources", $SystemID}]}
packageInstallDirectory = {FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, 
    "Applications"}]}
```

which give for my computer running under **Linux**:

> {"/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.2/SystemFiles/IncludeFiles/C",
>   "/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.2/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/
>   DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions"}
>
> {"/home/picaud/.Mathematica/SystemFiles/LibraryResources/Linux-x86-64"}
>
> {"/home/picaud/.Mathematica/Applications"}

where

- `libraryLinkIncludeDirectories` are the mma dynamic library directories
- `libraryInstallDirectory` is the user directory where to install the created dynamic library (the `libXXX.so` file).
- `packageInstallDirectory` is the user directory where to install the created package (the `package.wl` file).

**Questions**

**I need your help** because I only have access to computers under Linux and I want to check/fix the proposed approach to make it works for the **Windows** and **MacOS** OS.

1. In my `meson.build` files I use the `wolfram` command, but I am not sure it exists under Windows and MacOS, can you confirm that? (-> maybe I have to switch to the `wolframscript` command).
2. Under Windows and MacOS does the way I extract `libraryLinkIncludeDirectories, libraryInstallDirectory, packageInstallDirectory` makes sense/is correct??

Finally if you are interested, feel free to directly try the [github repository](https://github.com/vincent-picaud/mma_meson_demo) I would be happy to accept fix/pull request.

---

**update**: now it works under **Linux** and **MacOs**. Still have no access to **Windows** machine so I cannot test it.

Comment: This is nice. On Mac OS Mojave, the only thing I had to change is what is mentioned in Question 1. `wolfram` to `wolframscript`. Worked fine after that.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Thanks for the feed back! Glad to see it works under MacOS too. Also, plz pay attention that I just fixed a typo here and in the git repo: I originally forgot a 's' in a path (.../SystemFiles/LibraryResource`s`/...). Now this is fixed. Feel free to make an answer from your comment, I will be happy to vote it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Mac OS Mojave and Mathematica Version 11.3, the only modification required was to change `find_program('wolfram')` to `find_program('wolframscript')` in `meson.build`.

Sync'd my fork with your latest [commit](https://github.com/vincent-picaud/mma_meson_demo/commit/e96e8bcbc770e534babb377d35e7653226820954) and it worked fine without any changes.

`meson` was installed by `brew install meson`.